# In R: Force `foreach` loop to assign each computation inside the loop to a separate variable

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

So I have a `foreach` loop that assigns several different calculations inside the loop to separate variables. While running under a normal `for loop`, all variables are accessible, but when switching to a `foreach` loop, the function *only* returns the last 'stored' variable. How do I change this?

```
# assume the parallel processing is already set;
# won't affect the result

set.seed(1)

data <- dplyr::tibble(
  x = rnorm(5),
  y = rnorm(5, sd = 0.5),
  z = rnorm(5, sd = 0.25)
)

sims = 10

df = foreach(sim = 1:sims) %dopar% {
  
  calc <- data |> 
          furrr::future_pmap_dfr(
            function(x, y, z) {
              res <- (x + y) / z
              names(res) <- 'col'
              return(res)
            }
          )
  
  calc_2 <- data |>
            furrr::future_pmap_dfr(
              function(x, y, z) {
                res <- (x+y+z)^2
                names(res) <- 'col'
                return(res)
              }
            )
}
```

`df[[1]]` returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 1
    col
  <dbl>
1 0.434
2 0.275
3 0.387
4 1.77 
5 0.210
```

When switching the orders of `calc` and `calc_2`, the function now returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 1
     col
   <dbl>
1 -2.74 
2  4.38 
3  3.00 
4 -3.40 
5  0.629
```

This loop is not making the other calculation accessible, and when I run the `foreach` inside my real function -- which operates as intended using a `for loop` -- the function fails because only one of the three variables assigned in the `foreach` loop is stored and made accessible throughout the function call. **Similar to a `for loop`, how do I force the `foreach` loop to assign all variables calculated inside the loop so that they can be carried throughout the function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the list of results, and process accordingly.

```
df = foreach(sim = 1:sims) %dopar% {
  
  calc <- data |> 
          furrr::future_pmap_dfr(
            function(x, y, z) {
              res <- (x + y) / z
              names(res) <- 'col'
              return(res)
            }
          )
  
  calc_2 <- data |>
            furrr::future_pmap_dfr(
              function(x, y, z) {
                res <- (x+y+z)^2
                names(res) <- 'col'
                return(res)
              }
            )
  list(calc, calc_2)
}
```

`df` is now a list of length `sims`, where each element is a list of length 2, containing `calc` and `calc_2`